# Translate Odoo website content using Gettext PO file

Tags: internationalization, odoo-8, gettext, odoo-website

Is it possible to translate website content using **Gettext PO file**?

To begin we created a website using an Odoo built-in theme with the Website builder and we also translated the content using the **Green/Yellow tool** of the website builder.

Then when reaching our limits in terms of UI components we have decided to develop a custom theme for the website and when we switched to that given custom theme, all the previous translations we made **which was a huge amount of work** had suddenly been removed (we do not know why).

So we are trying to find a way to have more control over text and translations because of it being a huge amount of work.